# a single php while one three different classes

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have main div with three different classes: CLASS1; ClASS2 AND CLASS3. Now I want to use a single while loop in all classes to get three images from database and display.

First class is class1 then two div have same class class2 and then last div has class3. How to do it through loop, please help, Thanks :)

---

```
      <div class="col-md-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="ad1">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="ad2">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="ad2">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="ad3">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div> 

    </div> 

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM headerimages limit 4";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($query));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
```

Comment: Think what you mean to say is you have a 3 column layout and your inner divs need class="ad1" class="ad2" class="ad3" according  to their position in the columns.  Your classes aren't called class1 class2 class3. @ajmedway code below is correct you just need to change the `class="class<?` bit to  `class="ad<?`

Comment: @Dave that's because he changed the classes in the question

Answer (score 2):

**Answer updated to reflect changes in the Question**

I can see roughly what you are trying to achieve, hope this helps you...

```
<div class="col-md-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM headerimages limit 4";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($query));
    $class_number = 1;
    $class_two_repeated = FALSE;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        // This bit ensures the 2nd & 3rd divs have class 'ad2'
        if ($class_number == 3 && !$class_two_repeated) {
            $class_two_repeated = TRUE;
            $class_number--;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-<?= $class_number == 3 ? 5 : 2 ?>">
            <div class="ad<?= $class_number++ ?>">
                <img src="/path/to/<?= $row['whatever_the_image_field_is_named'] ?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: its not working i have three classes First div have class is ad1 the 2 divs has ad2 and then last div has class ad3 all three div's are in a single div

Comment: @MueenMehmoodWaseer "It's not working"? Could you please explain further? Any errors? What do you intend and what does this not achieve? Why does your db query SELECT with LIMIT 4 when there are three classes? Thanks

Comment: i will my db query has limit 4 mean just for images will display yes i have three class but 2nd class is same on two div's

its like this..
<div>
   <div class="ad1">HERE is IMAGE</div>

 <div class="ad2">HERE is IMAGE</div>

 <div class="ad2">HERE is IMAGE</div>

 <div class="ad3">HERE is IMAGE</div>
</div>

this is like this....Hope you understand.....

Comment: @MueenMehmoodWaseer this bears no resemblance to your original code in the question. You are making it tough to understand, please update your question accordingly and I will make a new answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok wait i am editing this question....

Comment: now check the code that i past in question this is my original html first div that having image has class ad1 then two div has ads2 and then last have class col-md-5...

Comment: OK, I see your changes... have another look at my answer, thanks. Please mark as the accepted answer if you are now happy :)

Comment: thanks its work.. but still a little issue that if u see my html code last div has class col-md-5...can u revised.....you answer.....

Comment: Yes I noticed that after my answer and edited it right away, please refresh and check again. Thanks :)

Comment: Thankuuuuuuuuuuuu So very Much Buddy ..........

Comment: @MueenMehmoodWaseer no problem, please could you tick my answer as the "accepted answer"? Thanks